# MS-DOS in a text file, how do I run this from command prompt?

Tags: replace, dos, notepad

I have an MS DOS command for Find and Replacing Text (FART) that I want to carry out on a group of text files. If I type this command into a text file and save it, is there anyway I can carry out the command in command prompt by somehow reading the text file from command prompt.

I'm very much a beginner, sorry if this is a trivial question, I'm new to programming.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file to filename.bat.

A .bat file (batch file) is just a sequence of DOS commands that when run will be executed in order.